# How I can set a session in codeigniter 3 database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I'm using the new version(3.0.0). of CodeIgniter and I have a new problem,  my sessions doesn't work. I mean, the code in the controller is correct because there are not errors but, when I try to print a PHP variable in a view there is nothing.

I checked my table in the MySQL Server, and nothing, I don't now what is the problem. I put my code of config.php. (I don't understand a lot of things in this new version)

```
$config['sess_table_name']              = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_driver']              = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name']             = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']          = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path']               = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip']                = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']      = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy']  = FALSE;
```

I have to add the first line to "make" sessions works,  I don't know if that configuration is correct to make sessions in a database.

If somebody has the same problem, help me please :( . My Session class has not been edited.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html
their see this topic Saving Session Data to a Database

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First of all [CI3 session table](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver) and CI2 session table( [Saving Session Data to a Database](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html))structure is different

New session table [structure](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver)

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Second They support [old configuration variables](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver) with [new configuration](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences) but it is better to use new configuration

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';//its your table name name
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

See more details at their [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Few new feature(function) available for session library.

**Remember** Don't forget it to load via autoload.php or loading `$this->load->library('session');` before use it.

Comment: Ooooh thanks bro, I was using the other table, I'll try. thanks a lot.

Comment: I change the sessions table, but my problem continues,
If I don't specify 
    $config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
MySQL send me a database error cuz the Update of the session doesn't have a target table. :(

Comment: You can use one.`$config['sess_save_path']` contains your table name.Do not use both.

Comment: If I don't use $config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions'; I got an error :(
I think that, CI continues using the 2.0 version of sessions or something like that

Comment: OK use it then.I checked the source of the library and saw it supports both.

Comment: And, here is my problem, if I use sess_table_name, CI try to insert a session on the old table, and my new configurations doesn't work :(

Comment: Download CI3 I think you using some files of CI2 or you upgraded CI2 to CI3 and it was not success

Comment: this is quite helpful, and if you want you can save session data into the file as well

Comment: I changed the setting as above and can save the session, but I can't read session from database and file.

Comment: I just rename the ci_sessions table name  in database to custom name, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the "first line" (i.e. `sess_table_name`) to make it work, that is because your `sess_driver` value is set to **database**. Take a look at the [list of supported drivers](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-drivers) and you will see that for file based sessions, it will default to that. In other words, if you remove these lines, it should work:

```
$config['sess_table_name']          = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_driver']              = 'database';
```

Comment: I try with that before, but I got a database error:
    UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1430946843, `user_data` = 'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data

The table is not established as you can see, if I delete the first line, the query to insert doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove that added line and set:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

Rest of code should be ok.
[Link to docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver).

Comment: I try with that before, but I got a database error: 
UPDATE SET last_activity = 1430946843, user_data = 'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data...
The table is not established as you can see, if I delete the first line, the query to insert doesn't work :(