# Codeigniter Sharing subdomain sessions on maindomain

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, subdomain, session-variables

Asking it again as I haven't received a single response :(

I have seen lots of debate on this question on stackoverflow, but I am not able to get a perfect answer. The issue is I have two domains maindomain.com and subdomain.com. (The subdomain is the subdomain of the maindomain)

When clicked on Login it is redirected to subdomain.com/login where a user is logged in and redirected to subdomain.com/dashboard. Thats fine but what I also want I want to access the session variables created by subdomain.com on maindomain.com so the user may know you are logged in on the subdomain etc.

I have consumed hours on playing with config.php file. If anyone can help me the steps which i can follow to make it work.

My maindomain/config.php code is something like this:

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "maindomain_";
$config['cookie_domain'] = ".maindomain.com";
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Is subdomain.com actually a subdomain of the maindomain.com? The placeholders you've used aren't very clear on that.

Comment: yea sorry about the confusion. Its the subdomain of the maindomain.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the session values of Subdomain on Main domain in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50103275/how-to-access-the-session-values-of-subdomain-on-main-domain-in-codeigniter) Just because your question isn't getting traction doesn't mean you should duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you will lose your session after the redirect, but you can change the session configuration to use the database,
[How I can set a session in codeigniter 3 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086348/how-i-can-set-a-session-in-codeigniter-3-database)
you can set up a trigger that fired whenever the user login and stored in new session on your subdomain, and destroy this session after logout,
That means two sessions one for each domain.
I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I have done something that stored JSON records in the database to control session records and communicate with other domains,

Answer (score 0):

add following code in your controller `__construct()` and remove all cache and check it will work.

```
public function __construct(){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type');

    parent::__construct();
}
```